# Why are my Access right modules not working

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, postgresql-9.5

I have some trouble when I tried to add access right to my project..
here's my loaded data in *manifest*.py

```
'data': [
    'security/ir.model.access.csv',
    'security/security.xml',
    'views/views.xml',
    'views/templates.xml',
    'views/partner.xml',        
],
```

and then here's my ir.model.access.csv code

```
  id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
kursus_user,kursus.user,model_training_kursus,group_training_user,1,1,1,1
sesi_user,sesi.user,model_training_sesi,group_training_user,1,1,1,1
kursus_create,kursus.create,model_training_kursus,group_training_create,1,0,1,0
kursus_read,kursus.read,model_training_kursus,group_training_read,1,0,0,0
kursus_update,kursus.update,model_training_kursus,group_training_update,1,1,0,0
kursus_delete,kursus.delete,model_training_kursus,group_training_delete,1,0,0,1
sesi_create,sesi.create,model_training_sesi,group_training_create,1,0,1,0
sesi_read,sesi.read,model_training_sesi,group_training_read,1,0,0,0
sesi_update,sesi.update,model_training_sesi,group_training_update,1,1,0,0
sesi_delete,sesi.delete,model_training_sesi,group_training_delete,1,0,0,1
```

and then here's my security.xml file

```
<odoo>
<record id='group_training_create' model='res.groups'>
    <field name='name'>Training / Akses Create</field>
</record>

<record id='group_training_read' model='res.groups'>
    <field name='name'>Training / Akses Read</field>
</record>

<record id='group_training_update' model='res.groups'>
    <field name='name'>Training / Akses Update</field>
</record>

<record id='group_training_delete' model='res.groups'>
    <field name='name'>Training / Akses Delete</field>
</record>


<record id='group_training_user' model='res.groups'>
    <field name='name'>Training / User</field>
</record>

<record id='group_training_manager' model='res.groups'>
    <field name='name'>Training / Manager</field>
    <field name='implied_ids' eval="[(4,ref('training_odoo.group_training_user'))]"/>
    <field name='users' eval='[(4, ref("base.user_root")'/>
</record>
```

when I run the code, I have error message like this

> Exception: Module loading training_odoo failed: file training_odoo/security/ir.model.access.csv could not be processed:
>    No matching record found for external id 'group_training_user' in field 'Group'

Can someone help me find the solution? maybe I have a typo there, but I don't know where it is

Answer (score 0):

Add `module_name` before `group_name`.

EX:

```
 sesi_user,sesi.user,model_training_sesi,module_name.group_training_user,1,1,1,1
```

Hope it will help you.